# pass data from activity one to activity three directly while going through activity two but data should not be passed to activity two

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three activities A,B and C. I need to pass some data from activity A to activity C. But the navigation is from A to B to C i.e. I can't go to activity C from activity A directly. I don't want to pass my data to activity B from A and I don't want to use any external storage like sqlite or shared preferences. Can it be done through intent ? If yes , how ? If no, is there any other way ?

Comment: in that case static variable is the only way.

Comment: `"I don't want to pass my data to activity B from A"` any reason why?

Comment: I want the  data to be hidden from activity B.

Comment: activity `B` is your activity, so what is the problem really?

Comment: Static is not recommended for this type of requirement you can always extend your application class to get the solution. Please see below the detail answer...

Comment: @PratikGoyal can you please tell a reason for not recommending `static`?

Comment: if u do not  need use of activity B then directly go in C ..why you more confuse and if want to go activity B then use data as static so easily access data hidden from B. @n9153

Comment: This was an android interview question asked to me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes sure.
for example in your Activity

```
class ActivityA extend Activity{
    public static String abc = "hello";

}

in ActivityC

ActivityC extend Activity{

    onCreate(){
        String a = ActivityA.abc;
        Log.d("test",a);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the most appropriate and shortest solution

Comment: Static variable within a Activity class is not a good solution

Comment: read my old comments, i said use Interfaces or static method. @n9153 found static way as best solution.

Answer (score 0):

use Interface to communicate with other Activity.

or you can make your variable `public static` on Activity1

Comment: thanks pawneshwar for the response. can you please explain and elaborate a little ?

Comment: yes sure.
for example in your Activity

   class ActivityA extend Activity{
 public static String abc = "hello";

}

in ActivityC

ActivityC extend Activity{

 onCreate(){
  String a = ActivityA.abc;
  Log.d("test",a);
 }
}

Comment: check my new response with example

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to send the data from one activity to other activity,

Now as you can not use intent so I would suggest you to go with either Application class or create a Global singleton class to hold your data.

Please refer following link
[https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/defining-global-variables-in-android/](http://Defining%20Global%20Variables%20in%20Android)

Following are the steps to create an application class: 
Step 1: Create any class and extend it with the Application class:

```
public class Globals extends Application{
   private int data=200;

   public int getData(){
     return this.data;
   }

   public void setData(int d){
     this.data=d;
   }
}
```

Step 2: Defining the application class in the manifest file:

```
<application
   android:name=".Globals"
   .... />
```

Step 3:Now by calling getApplication() in any of the activity you get your application class. Just typecast it and call the methods required.

```
Globals g = (Globals)getApplication();
int data=g.getData();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Also Don't go with the easy solution of defining a static variable as this is not a tall recommended.

Comment: no, **you should use** static singletons, read `Appication` javadocs: `"There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way"`

Comment: Yes creating a singleton is good solution and that is what I have suggested in the second option but creating a static variable within a Activity is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your third activity has no way of knowing which activity sent the bundle. You need to add a field that identifies what type of bundle this is so you can process accordingly. For instance, in activity 1:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("activity", (int)1);
    i.putExtra("key", value);
    startActivity(i);
```

Then in 3rd activity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) { 
   int typeAct = extras.getInt("activity");
   if (typeAct == 1) {
//do something with data
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

make one interface :

```
public interface PassData {
public void data(String data);
}
```

if you want to pass the data from activity A to activity C then :
from Activity A you need to pass the data like this:then on Activity A.

```
PassData passData;// make it global variable
passData.data("Your DATA WHICH YOU WANT TO SEND TO ACTIVITY C");
```

In Activity C :

```
ActivityC extends AppCompatActivity implements PassData{
//onCreate Stuff

 @Override
    public void data(String data) {
  // print this data and see it's coming or not

}
```